# Как найти базу данных SQLite в Android Studio?

Tags: android, sqlite

Всем привет. Сразу говорю: кто-то задавал этот же вопрос, но на него никто не ответил корректно.
Не могу найти базу данных SQLite в Android Studio. Нет вообще нигде, будто её нет вовсе. А хотя она работает. Код работы БД на скриншоте. Открывал Android Device Monitor - File Explorer - там пусто.
[image: Код]

Answer (score 3):

Ее и не должно быть в Android Studio (что бы вы там не имели ввиду по этим).

SQLite БД обычно расположена на девайсе в каталоге: `/data/data/[имя пакета]/databases`, точное место расположения возвращает метод: `Context.getDatabasePath()`

Попробуйте открыть монитор в набрать (работает на эмуляторе):

```
 adb shell
 cd /data/data/[my.application.package]/databases
 ls
```

Comment: Я не понял, куда вводить то, что Вы мне написали. И нет у меня такого пути на смартфоне. Находит папку databases, но она пустая.

Comment: надеюсь вы не вводите именно так как я написал, а вставляете имя своего пакета :)

Comment: Это понятно, но куда вводить? В строку Quick Access?

Comment: внизу такая кнопочка/бар есть *terminal* - нажимаете туда, откроется окошечко туда и вбивайте (OMG)